# Get category URL for current post

Tags: functions, categories

I am using this code to retrieve the category of the current post.

```
<?php $category = get_the_category();
$firstCategory = $category[0]->cat_name; echo $firstCategory;?>
```

How could I get the category URL without running another database query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the category id into `get_category_link()`:

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category();
$link = get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id );
?>
```

**Update** Outputting in template:

```
<?php
$category = get_the_category();
$first_category = $category[0];
echo sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_category_link( $first_category ), $first_category->name );
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't run another database query. Everything needed to construct the URL was returned whenever the category was first queried and put into the object cache. I just did a quick test and adding get_category_link didn't increase the number of queries according to Query Monitor.

Comment: ok this looks promising.. i am having trouble putting this together as <a href="$link">$category</a> . could you help please ?

Comment: I updated by answer.

Comment: No problem. If you can accept my answer that would be swell ;)

Comment: Works like a charm on 2023, thanks